# How to set Navigation bar and Tab bar as pass through views of a UIPopoverViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-group

I have custom a UIViewController as a PopoverViewController and when I present it I can't touch on Navigation bar neither Tab bar

I have search for while and I got:
In prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) of first ViewController code:

```
if segue.identifier == "ShowChoice"{
      let poper = segue.destination
      poper.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
      poper.popoverPresentationController?.delegate = self
      let point = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY + 5)
      poper.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
      poper.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = CGRect(origin: point, size: CGSize.zero)
      poper.popoverPresentationController?.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirection(rawValue: 0)

//here I set [self.view] to passthroughViews and it work i can interact with all thing in self.view but I can't interact with Navigation Button or Tab bar item!

            poper.popoverPresentationController?.passthroughViews = [self.view]
        }
    }
```

I can set only UIView to passthroughViews but I want to set Navigation Bar or Tab Bar

thank you!

Comment: You have to show a bit more context (more code) here as this works fine for me. From your line of code we can't tell where you are trying to set this from or if it's all hooked up correctly.

Comment: @Terje I have updated Could you please have a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found on my own by simply cast [self.tabBarController?.tabBar,self.navigationController?.navigationBar] to [UIView]

```
poper.popoverPresentationController?.passthroughViews = [self.tabBarController?.tabBar,self.navigationController?.navigationBar] as! [UIView]
```

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, the order of items inside `popoverPresentationController.passthroughViews` does matter!

For example if you wanted to add all your views AND your navigation bar, you MUST put your navigation bar at the start of the list, otherwise touches will just be fed to whatever item is under it

Here's my code:

```
 popoverPresentationController.passthroughViews = [self.view]
 if let navBar = self.navigationController?.navigationBar {
     popoverPresentationController.passthroughViews?.insert(navBar, at: 0)
 }
```

Also, remember to dismiss the popoverView if you're doing this for being able to use the back button